# Starter solenoid breakdown

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starter, wiring, triumph

Triumph T100 motorcycle, starter solenoid clicks a lot and doesn't turn motor enough, it would start after pressing starter button for a length of time but solenoid would then break. When my original solenoid broke down a wire inside it had melted and broke. I put a new solenoid on, it worked good at first then started clicking a lot, then stuck open so when I got home and turned ignition off it wouldn't stop turning engine over, so solenoid and starter were still live. I had to disconnect battery to stop it. I put another solenoid on it and that clicked a lot then would start but that solenoid then broke.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a bad ground or wiring problem causing low voltage  to  the starter motor , which will cause clicking for the starter motor , same thing happens when battery is low on motorbike.Low voltage = more  current needed  to  compensate for same actuation force  on solenoid = burned solenoid.

Answer (score -1):

The starter relay switch gives the starter the juice so if its bad normaly that would make the bike not start and therefore put to much stress on the starter if you keep trying to start it so change the relay and if the starter cyl. still is a problem you have a loose wire that is grounded and it is messing up that part so look around the bike for any wires that are grounded also.